# SoundCloud user Authentication

Tags: javascript, php, soundcloud

I am trying to authenticate user via soundcloud's javascript api.

Main file (http://www.jobjiant.com/sc/soundCloud.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sc.js"></script>

<script>
var a="a";
    var userId;
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: '52dd38ea253742f5f15cf995a2303273',
        redirect_uri: 'http://www.jobjiant.com/sc/callback.php'
    });
$(document).on('click','.download',function(){
        SC.connect().then(function() {
             return SC.get('/me');
        }).then(function(me) {
            alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Callback file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
    <script>
    alert(window.opener.a);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html
```

**The Problem**

When I use redirect url as http://www.jobjiant.com/sc/callback.php the error is
Permission denied to access property "a"
and
Permission denied to access property "setTimeout"

But
When I use redirect url as http://jobjiant.com/sc/callback.php their is no error but the authentication window doesn't close automatically.